# Silverlight 4: Pattern for displaying data with a bit of logic?

Tags: silverlight, user-interface

I'm building a wp7 app.

I have a `UserControl` that displays a news article headline, teaser, and image. The entire class is pretty short:

```
public partial class StoryControl : UserControl
{
    public Story Story { get; private set; }

    public StoryControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    internal StoryControl(Story story) : this()
    {
        this.Story = story;
        Teaser.Text = story.Teaser;
        Headline.Text = story.Title;

        if (story.ImageSrc == null)
        {
            Thumbnail.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        } else
        {
            Thumbnail.Source = new BitmapImage(story.ImageSrc);
        }
    }
}
```

And the corresponding XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" Margin="0,0,0,20">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Image x:Name="Thumbnail" Grid.Column="0" Width="89" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

    <!-- sometimes there's a hanging word in the headline that looks a bit awkward -->
    <TextBlock x:Name="Headline" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextAccentStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="23.333" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="Teaser" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="384"/>
</Grid>
```

Is there a way to do with with less code-behind and more XAML? Some way to use binding to bind the text for `Headline` and `Teaser` to properties of the `Story`, while not crashing if `Story` is null?

About about the image? I've got a bit of logic there; is there some way to automatically do that in XAML, or am I stuck with that in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a ViewModel is in order:

```
public class StoryViewModel
{
    readonly Story story;

    public StoryViewModel(Story story)
    {
        this.story = story;
    }

    public string Teaser { get { return story == null ? "" : story.Teaser; } }
    public string Title { get { return story == null ? "" : story.Title; } }
    public bool IsThumbnailVisible { get { return story != null && story.ImageSrc != null; } }
    public BitmapImage Thumbnail { get { return IsThumbnailVisible ? new BitmapImage(story.ImageSrc) : null; } }
}
```

Making your codebehind nice and simple:

```
public partial class StoryControl : UserControl
{
    public Story Story { get; private set; }

    public StoryControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    internal StoryControl(Story story)
        : this()
    {
        this.DataContext = new StoryViewModel(story);
    }
}
```

And your XAML becomes a set of bindings:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" Margin="0,0,0,20">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="booleanToVisiblityConverter"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Image Visibility="{Binding IsThumbnailVisible, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisiblityConverter}}" Source="{Binding Thumbnail}" Grid.Column="0" Width="89" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

    <!-- sometimes there's a hanging word in the headline that looks a bit awkward -->
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextAccentStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="23.333" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Teaser}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="384"/>

</Grid>
```

Ok, it would probably be possible to do this with just model (story) and view (xaml) via fallbackvalues and more complex converters, but i hope you'll find that viewmodels give you the most power in terms of testable, brick-wall-less, view-specific logic...

Comment: Looks good, although I'm having trouble with `booleanToVisiblityConverter`. I need to do something with static resources?

Comment: Edited to include the actual converter in a static resource. Normally you'd declare this at a higher level such as Window or App

Comment: Ok. I'm getting an error that it can't be found. Is it not supported on the Windows Phone 7?

Comment: BooleanToVisibilityConverter would have to be a custom converter that you create.  BooleanToVisibilityConverter exists in WPF but not in WP7 (which is based on Silverlight 3).
Here's a sample BooleanToVisibilityConverter.
http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/6758589c3549#src%2fCaliburn.Micro.Silverlight%2fBooleanToVisibilityConverter.cs
And here's a link on how to use converters.

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/07/30/format-data-in-silverlight-databinding-valueconverter.aspx

Comment: Thanks Joe! I completely missed the OP's first sentence :S

Comment: NP! Awesome that you were able to answer the question based on WPF knowledge.  ;]